# Upgrading projects from .Net 4.6.1 to 4.7.x causes errors in WCF Reference.cs

Tags: c#, wcf, asmx

I have a project consuming an ancient ASMX service. While sitting at .Net Framework 4.6.1, I can add a reference to the service and I get no issues. But once I upgrade the project to 4.7 or 4.7.x, I start getting this error(s):

```
'FlightSchedule': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type
```

I get this on three types. Apart from the error in code, here are the warnings I get if I try to remove and add the service or update existing:

```
Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:binding[@name='DIAFlightScheduleHttpGet']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:service[@name='DIAFlightSchedule']/wsdl:port[@name='DIAFlightScheduleHttpGet']
D:\Projects\...\Connected Services\FISAirline\Reference.svcmap  1

Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:binding[@name='DIAFlightScheduleHttpPost']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:service[@name='DIAFlightSchedule']/wsdl:port[@name='DIAFlightScheduleHttpPost']
D:\Projects\...\Connected Services\FISAirline\Reference.svcmap  1

Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: The required WSDL extension element 'binding' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/' was not handled.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:binding[@name='DIAFlightScheduleHttpGet']
D:\Projects\...\Connected Services\FISAirline\Reference.svcmap  1

Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: The required WSDL extension element 'binding' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/' was not handled.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:binding[@name='DIAFlightScheduleHttpPost']
D:\Projects\...\Connected Services\FISAirline\Reference.svcmap  1
```

I'm not able to figure this one out. If I google the warnings, there are pointers to update the app.config but no protocols are there for me to remove. And I cannot find anything relatable if I search on the error.

I need to update to the latest framework v4.8.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove the service reference and add the service reference again? This ancient service called XML web service other than WCF service. The error typically indicates that there are ambiguous understanding with some class definitions during the compilation(the namespace issue of class), which seems to nothing with the issue.  Generally speaking, the XML web service is compatible with the high version DotNet framework. At least, I could not reproduce your problem on my side.
Xml web service is obsolete. WCF created by BasicHttpBinding is well compatible with the traditional soap web service. I suggest you re-construct your service project.Alternatively, Asp.net WebAPI could create modern web service, which is widely used on the internet.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Touching the existing API is out of the picture. And I did removed and added the service as well. As long as I stay on or under .Net Framework v4.6.1, the client is generated properly. It generates three types that are of the same name as the class.